# PhpStorm Xdebug connected but not stopped

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

Hello yesterday I've had faced strange issue with xdebug in PhpStorm.
As you can see I pass the PhpStorm validation:

[image: PHP Validation]

But when I enable listener and start debug session, it just hangs.

[image: Storm]

[image: Browser]

Also in xdebug logs I can see right file name and line on which it must stop. But PhpStorm doesn't show me that break.

If there is no breakpoint site loads correctly. If I enable PhpStorm's option "Break at first line in PHP scripts" it correctly stops in index.php but I can't step over/in. (just hangs)

It would be great if someone can help me.

P.S. My Xdebug was working for years, yesterday i reinstall Apache and this issue happened, already tried to completely reinstall PHP and Apache, issue still persist.

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version? You need PhpStorm 2018.3.x or newer for Xdebug 2.7. So either upgrade PhpStorm to the latest stable 2018.3.x or downgrade Xdebug to 2.6.x (which you did already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research i found this
[topic](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001498520-xdebug-works-only-with-first-line). 
I check my phpstorm log and found exact same error:

***ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Argument for @NotNull parameter 'remoteFileUrl' of com/jetbrains/php/debug/xdebug/debugger/XdebugDriver.onBreak must not be null ...***

Solution was to intall older version of xdebug. I just install 2.6.1 (2.7.0 was installed) and all works now.